# How to set a geometry to NA (empty) for some features of an sf dataframe in R

Tags: r, sf, dplyr

I would like to set to empty the geometries of some features of my `sf` object given a condition.
Here is my code:

```
my_points %<>% mutate(geometry = if_else(district_x != district_y, st_sfc(rep(st_point(), nrow(.))), geometry))
```

Basically, my dataframe contains two text columns named `district_x` and `district_y` respectively and a POINT geometry `(sfc)` column named geometry. Everytime the value in `district_x` is different from the value in `district_y`, I want to set the geometry of that feature to `Empty`.

With this code above, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in `stopifnot()`:
ℹ In argument: `geometry = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `vapply()`:
! values must be length 3,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1
```

Any hints?

Comment: You can assign empty geometries by piping NULL into the associated features using ``st_geometry` for example,  `st_geometry(pts)[which(pts$district_x == pts$district_y)] <- NULL` The call to `which` is simply creating an index, of the resulting query, that references the corresponding row number.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set the geometry elements to `st_empty()` using a logical subselection. Here's a reproducible example that only uses the `sf` package - you seem to have some other unstated packages attached.

First lets make a sample data set:

```
d = st_as_sf(
data.frame(
district_x=c(1,2,3,4),district_y=c(1,5,3,2),
x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,3,4)),
coords=c("x","y"))
```

Which is this:

```
> d
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 4 ymax: 4
CRS:           NA
  district_x district_y    geometry
1          1          1 POINT (1 1)
2          2          5 POINT (2 2)
3          3          3 POINT (3 3)
4          4          2 POINT (4 4)
```

Which rows are we interested in? Let's compare columns:

```
> d$district_x == d$district_y
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Change those elements:

```
d$geometry[d$district_x == d$district_y] = st_point()
```

And now they are changed:

```
> d
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields (with 2 geometries empty)
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2 ymin: 2 xmax: 4 ymax: 4
CRS:           NA
  district_x district_y    geometry
1          1          1 POINT EMPTY
2          2          5 POINT (2 2)
3          3          3 POINT EMPTY
4          4          2 POINT (4 4)
```

Actually I'm not sure if I've changed the ones you want or the ones you didn't, but flip the test if so. Like:

```
> # reset `d`:
> d = st_as_sf(data.frame(district_x=c(1,2,3,4),district_y=c(1,5,3,2),x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,3,4)), coords=c("x","y"))
> # test and set
> d$geometry[d$district_x != d$district_y] = st_point()
> # look
> d
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields (with 2 geometries empty)
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
CRS:           NA
  district_x district_y    geometry
1          1          1 POINT (1 1)
2          2          5 POINT EMPTY
3          3          3 POINT (3 3)
4          4          2 POINT EMPTY
```

The principle is: Create a vector of TRUE/FALSE for each row, set the geometry for the TRUE elements.

Strictly you should probably use `st_geometry` to get the geometry rather than `$geometry` since it might not be named that way in another data set:

```
> st_geometry(d)[d$district_x != d$district_y] = st_point()
```

Note this doesn't need any other packages which seem to be confusing you. Using simple constructions that can be easily taken apart and inspected will advance your learning.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves my problem. Now for a follow up question, I would now want to replace these empty geometries I just created with point geometries created from XY coordinates created in columns name `X` and `Y` respectively.  `my_points %<>% mutate(geometry= if_else(st_is_empty(geometry), st_sfc(st_point(c(X, Y))), geometry))`. I really don't know why it's not working. I scrolled through half of SO without luck now.